# Open source polynomial solver

Tags: polynomials

I need to solve a 6th degree polynomial in my software, so I am looking for an open source numerical polynomial solver.

If you know of anything that could be of use to me, please post it here.

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Try https://scicomp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Will do. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need a numerical approximation or an exact solution?  I'm pretty sure there are formulas for the 6th degree, you just can't make a formual that only uses elementary operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) and taking roots.  But if you add some other operations then I believe there is a forumula.

Comment: An approximation should be OK, depending how precise it is.

Comment: You can use Newton's method usually to get as accurate as you want.  There are online calculators that will do Newton for you, for example this one: https://www.shodor.org/unchem/advanced/newton/nmethod.html